# Starting multiple sessions in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to start 3 sessions when the user logs in.
But the only session that is being started is the `$email=$_POST['email']`

Here is my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['log'])) // code to be executed when login button is clicked
{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['Password'];

    $query= "SELECT * FROM student 
    WHERE EmailAddress = '$email' AND Password = '$password'";

    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
    {
        //checks the database where this user exist or not

        $_SESSION['email']=$email;
        $_SESSION['StudentID']=$student;
        $_SESSION['OfferingID']=$Offering;


        header('location: profile.php'); //
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("Invalid Credentials or Not yet registered!") </script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by started? And did you start the session(`session_start()`)? And `$email=$_POST['email']` is not part of `$_SESSION`

Comment: First define the $student and $offering variables...

Comment: I don't see the `$student` and `$Offering` being initialized

Comment: @Swellar That's what I'm saying...

Comment: Sorry...Yes I did put session start...the problem I,m unable to use the variable is my other pages even though I have `session start()`...but when I use the `print_r function`...it only prints the `$_SESSION['email']=$email;` but not the others.

Comment: You need to assign values to student and offering variables.

Comment: @YashParekh We commented at almost the same time

Comment: I'm new in php..how can I initialize the other two variables?

Comment: @hades The way you initialized `$email`

Comment: GIve me field names. I'll generate your code...

Comment: @hades What we mean is that both `$student` and `$Offering` does not have any value when you assigned them, so put some value first so that you can use `$_SESSION['StudentID']` and `$_SESSION['OfferingID']`

Comment: OK let me try first

Comment: @YashParekh the `$offeringID` is in a another table and `$studentID` is in another table.

Comment: @hades Just give me fields of both the tables. I'll built your code...

Comment: @YashParekh `Student(StudentID,FirstName,LastName,Email,Gender) , Offering(OfferingID,Semester,Year)`

Comment: @hades There must be a common field between these two tables to fetch the relational data...

Comment: @YashParekh Yes there is a junction table. `Participates(studentPartID,OfferingNo)` which reference back to those two tables.

Comment: @hades Is `Student(StudentID)` and `Participates(studentPartID)` both are same??

Comment: @YashParekh Yes they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['log']))
{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['Password'];

    $query= "SELECT * FROM student WHERE EmailAddress = '$email' AND Password = '$password'";

    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
    {
        $fetch_student_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
        $select_offer_id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Participants where studentID=".$fetch_student_data['StudentID']);
        $fetch_offer_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_offer_id);

        $_SESSION['email']=$email;
        $_SESSION['StudentID']=$fetch_student_data['StudentID'];
        $_SESSION['OfferingID']=$fetch_offer_id['OfferingID'];

        header('location: profile.php'); //
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("Invalid Credentials or Not yet registered!") </script>';
    }
}
```

I've edited my answer..
Just check for proper field and table names..
Rest of the code are set
Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the studentID and offering are from the database record, you need to fetch the data and extract those fields from the record fetched.

Something like...

```
    $student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
    $_SESSION['StudentID']=$student['studentID'];
    $_SESSION['OfferingID']=$student['OfferingID'];
```

Comment: Can I insert this inside the `isset function`?

Comment: this is may me correct 
 $student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
        $_SESSION['email']=$email;
        $_SESSION['StudentID']=$student['studentID'];
        $_SESSION['OfferingID']=$student['OfferingID'];

Answer (score 0):

**first get $student and $offering inside condition in your code like this**

```
if(isset($_POST['log'])) // code to be executed when login button is clicked
{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['Password'];

    $query= "SELECT * FROM student 
    WHERE EmailAddress = '$email' AND Password = '$password'";

    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
    {
        //fetch array and get values for studentid and offeringid
        $student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
    $_SESSION['StudentID']=$student['studentID'];
    $_SESSION['OfferingID']=$student['OfferingID'];


        header('location: profile.php'); //
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("Invalid Credentials or Not yet registered!") </script>';
    }
}
```

**here i set  check again**